# Django syncdb error: One or more models did not validate

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

/mysite/project4

```
 class notes(models.Model):
   created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
   detail = models.ForeignKey(Details)
```

Details and User are in the same module i.e,/mysite/project1
In project1 models i have defined

```
   class User():
      ......

   class Details():
      ......
```

When DB i synced there is an error saying

`Error: One or more models did not validate:
project4: Accessor for field 'detail' clashes with related field . Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'detail'.`

How can this be solved..

thanks..

Comment: If it is useful to anyone, I got this same error because I was using a 3rd party lib, taggit, that I had referenced but not put into my installed apps category.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gee we just had this one; and I answered...

You have a number of foreign keys which django is unable to generate unique names for.

You can help out by adding "related_name" arguments to the foreignkey field definitions in your models. Eg:

```
 class notes(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="note_created_by_user")
    detail = models.ForeignKey(Details, related_name="noted_and_detailed")
```

See here for more. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name