# Django mysql table name did not validate

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm, mysql-python

I added classes to Django app model to create mysql tables. I have 'downloads' table, and 'downloads' column in 'songs' table.

When i want to sync db, Django returns me error:

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
mp3mid.downloads: Reverse query name for field 'song' clashes with field 'songs.downloads'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'song'.
```

Why it's impossible to give same name to table and column?

this is my models.py:

```
from django_evolution.mutations import *
from django.db import models

class singers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(categories)

class songs(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    singer = models.ForeignKey(singers)
    downloads = models.IntegerField(max_length = 11)
    exclusive = models.BooleanField(default = 0)
    hit = models.BooleanField(default = 0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    link = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

class downloads(models.Model):
    song = models.ForeignKey(songs)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

Comment: could you post your model classes

Comment: what about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608017/django-syncdb-error-one-or-more-models-did-not-validate?rq=1

Comment: @dm03514 added models.py file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django allows you to [make queries that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

In your case, the foreign key from `downloads` to `songs` means you could usually make queries that follow the relationship backwards from song to downloads:

```
from datetime import datetime
# fetch all songs with a download with a date on or after 2013-05-01.
songs = song.objects.filter(downloads__date__gte=datetime(2013,5,1))
```

However, you can't do that in this case, because `downloads` clashes with your `songs.downloads` field.

You have a couple of options. First, you can set [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for your foreign key, as suggested by your error message.

```
class downloads(models.Model):
    song = models.ForeignKey(songs, related_name="related_downloads")
```

Or, you can rename your `song.downloads` field.

```
class songs(models.Model):
    ...
    num_downloads = models.IntegerField(max_length = 11)
```

As an aside, I recommend you rename your models to `Singer`, `Song` and `Download` (capitalized, singular instead of plural), to follow the Django convention.