# DatabaseError python manage.py syncdb

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm learning django framework and i  have a problem with django When you start the syncdb
help me please, how to correct error?

used files

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'djangodb1',                      
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'toor',
        'HOST': '',                    
        'PORT': '',                   
    }
}

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'testsite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^testsite/', include('testsite.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

---

```
root@lhackg:~/testsite# python manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table django_admin_log


DatabaseError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s  AND `django_content_type`.`app_label` = %s )' at line 1")
```

Comment: This could be related: http://grokbase.com/p/gg/django-updates/129hmzh0q4/django-18970-django-python-3-experimental-support-python-manage-py-syncdb-1064-error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django syncdb error: One or more models did not validate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608017/django-syncdb-error-one-or-more-models-did-not-validate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an extension to @karthikr's comment above, [the ticket regarding this issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18970) has been "fixed" and closed - although you will notice the fix is merely a change in the documentation acknowledging the problems of porting Django to Python 3.

You have 2 realistic options at this point:

1. Use Python 2.x and keep using MySql.
2. Use Python 3.x and change your database backend.

Comment: how to change database? i use django 1.5 and python 3.2